# How to let docker container log output sdb disk in Azure cloud

Tags: azure-virtual-machine

Currently, my cloud environment based on Azure cloud and the VM type is D3V2(14G/200G), Azure VM provide OS disk called sda that has 30 GB, and Ephemeral disk called sdb that has 200 GB. My container orchestration is based on mesos/marathon, all containers logs output to sda not sdb, so after several days, the disk space is full. How to utilize the sdb disk and let the logs can output to sdb?

following is output of `df -k` in my VM:

```
root@dcos-agentprivate-service000003:/home/test# df -k
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev             7155096       0   7155096   0% /dev
tmpfs            1435028  134880   1300148  10% /run
/dev/sda1       30428648 7590548  22821716  25% /
tmpfs            7175128       0   7175128   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120       0      5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            7175128       0   7175128   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
overlay         30428648 7590548  22821716  25% /var/lib/docker/overlay/2f479dc1d57d3ef848f957ae4b1751dc68eafab44249aa2028492eb44491ba9a/merged
shm                65536       0     65536   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/6301aefde9113502687503e77e65ce6bb8c2d39eb678944c10a41198cbd58e74/shm
overlay         30428648 7590548  22821716  25% /var/lib/docker/overlay/89ce9ca51728b61d29778131a7f2e6b859cba6b70b1777664d62b5154f741ac8/merged
shm                65536       0     65536   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/5bb83ee7bd75b92c16044d03b216754e127ca9d53eb3fb17df88f881f7928f79/shm
overlay         30428648 7590548  22821716  25% /var/lib/docker/overlay/4986839f2046dab76caacea057590af338433dda133165920facf8b62901bbf4/merged
shm                65536       0     65536   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/58eb5ae765785d35941133607e9667214c65a89743325767755b4ff3f4a89e27/shm
overlay         30428648 7590548  22821716  25% /var/lib/docker/overlay/ca68a2ce6c4b35a0efc2d8d5748e295686402f195b62bcf5aeb5e0b7b0d8af6c/merged
shm                65536       0     65536   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/619b5dac97338672669420f9aec7cd72b83ed2cd170d0f3f98ca8bdc4a139d77/shm
overlay         30428648 7590548  22821716  25% /var/lib/docker/overlay/b1e4f59da0d59d1cfff6725827dad8da1bc80913c37be8b3468bcd103a781c53/merged
shm                65536       0     65536   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/5127f81741c87759df9865a417beaf2c8d09871680b6de66b5e3cbe51385354d/shm
overlay         30428648 7590548  22821716  25% /var/lib/docker/overlay/65a999e7d61d67384db9e955cf55a363129d124dc5385fe38ccd0688053239f2-init/merged
overlay         30428648 7590548  22821716  25% /var/lib/docker/overlay/8356b0e83f436e02a7445cdc1a89286cdd731f57826dccf98f4e46b006f430e0-init/merged
overlay         30428648 7590548  22821716  25% /var/lib/docker/overlay/28eecf196b970f824e72bdf000a6da4725be3408ec47d3c6477054e39c12167f-init/merged
overlay         30428648 7590548  22821716  25% /var/lib/docker/overlay/3c12ab53b60588bba34b96eca8591ec063bc9072ac925b6e8f2d1e9f62492583-init/merged
overlay         30428648 7590548  22821716  25% /var/lib/docker/overlay/465eb669a1bc191e9a798636b5441ccdc4d9f414063cd9a83c3921a633e8c2c5-init/merged
overlay         30428648 7590548  22821716  25% /var/lib/docker/overlay/7210916bf5ffe265223c71d902e9c34ab8a1489655470cba94b7d6a8d5123991-init/merged
tmpfs            1435028       0   1435028   0% /run/user/1000
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to utilize the sdb disk and let the logs can output to sdb?

I don't think it is a good idea, because when the VM restart, any data saved on the previous temporary drive will not be migrated.

**The temporary storage must not be used to store data that you are not willing to lose.**

You can mount another disk to that VM, then change DC/OS log path config settings.

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.